# Templates in typo3

Tags: templates, typo3

I'm looking for some help about Typo3,
is about 3 day that I'm tring to set a different template for each page, form templates dir, but without any success, :((
I'm tring the backend_layout too, and same, only error.
I'm really desperated.....
I followed step by step docs and tutorial more the 4 times.....  :-((((((
Is my first week with Typo3, maybe I did something wrong....
I'm whatched I think more than 20 video tutorial, but maybe missing some step that they didn't show at the beginning...
Help please......
Thank you

Comment: please be more specific: give us information about what versions you are using (OS, TYPO3, extensions, ...), what tutorials did you follow?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Stack Overflow only for specific questions. See also [Stack Overflow: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

The **most recent tutorial** about templating in TYPO3 is the [official Site Package tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/). It was written for TYPO3 v8, but is still valid for TYPO3 v9.

You can also register to [the official TYPO3 Slack channels](https://typo3.slack.com/) to ask some more general questions or advice.

Comment: screenshots? I would consider it bad style to answer questions here if important information is given somewhere else.

Comment: These screenshots were posted here, but got removed later on. I agree, the new contributor isn't using SO right, which makes answering difficult.